# How to create sql partitions for multiple columns?

Tags: oracle

I try to create partitions for a table. I want to create partitions for 2 different columns. Is it possible?

So this works:

```
  ALTER TABLE MY)TABLE MODIFY
    PARTITION BY RANGE(SETTLEMENT_DATE) INTERVAL(NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'day'))
( partition MY_PARTITION values less than (to_date('2019-06-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')));
```

This is what I would like to do, but it does not work:

```
  ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE MODIFY
    PARTITION BY RANGE(FILE_SUBMISSION_DATE_TIME) INTERVAL(NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'day'))
( partition MY_PARTITION values less than (to_date('2016-06-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'))),
    PARTITION BY RANGE(FILE_ACK_DATE_TIME) INTERVAL(NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'day'))
( partition MY_PARTITION_2 values less than (to_date('2016-06-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')));
```

Comment: What you partition is the table, not columns. You might be able to do what you want using subpartitions (search for "oracle composite partitioning").

Comment: @Mat composite partitioning is not really what I need. I need to create partitions that would help me find the data by date. I have 2 columns containing date data and they do not really have a relationship that would allow me to use composite partitions.

Comment: Are you sure you need partitions at all? Indexes are what you use to "help find the data by date"

Comment: @Mat The table will contain a lot of data. I was using indexes but was told to try partitions if possible. I did it for some tables, but as you see in this example some selects will be done by FILE_SUBMISSION_DATE_TIME and some by FILE_ACK_DATE_TIME and I was wondering if partitions could be applied here.

Comment: You don't have to have a relationship between columns to do composite partitioning. In fact, what you are looking for is what composite partitioning does. Thing is you cannot subpartition just one partition.

Comment: @gsalem Lets suppose I do partitions on FILE_SUBMISSION_DATE_TIME and subpartitions based on the FILE_ACK_DATE_TIME. How will this affect a select that is done only on FILE_ACK_DATE_TIME? Will there be any improvements in performance and would it make sense. I guess not, but please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I guess what I want to do is not possible. It would be like attributing 1 row to 2 partitions...

Answer (score 0):

You can partition on two columns in two ways:

- Multi-column partitioning
- Composite partitioning (one partition column, one subpartition column)

**Multi-column partitioning**

This uses the first column to choose which partition to place a row in. The second column is only evaluated when there is a tie. This can lead to rows being in a partition you didn't expect:

```
create table t (
  c1 int, c2 int, c3 int
) partition by range ( c1, c2 ) (
  partition p0 values less than ( 1, 1 ),
  partition p1 values less than ( 2, 2 ),
  partition p2 values less than ( 3, 3 )
);

insert into t values ( 0, 0,  1 );
insert into t values ( 0, 99, 2 );
insert into t values ( 1, 1,  3 );

select * from t partition ( p0 );

C1    C2     C3   
    0     0     1 
    0    99     2
```

Filtering on the second column in the list will minimal partition pruning:

```
alter session set statistics_level = all;
set serveroutput off

select * from t 
where  c2 = 0;

select * 
from   table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(null, null, 'ROWSTATS LAST +PARTITION'));

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
| Id  | Operation                    | Name | Starts | E-Rows | Pstart| Pstop | A-Rows |    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |      |      1 |        |       |       |      1 |    
|   1 |  PARTITION RANGE MULTI-COLUMN|      |      1 |      1 |KEY(MC)|KEY(MC)|      1 |    
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL          | T    |      3 |      1 |KEY(MC)|KEY(MC)|      1 |    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

(note the `Starts = 3` for `TABLE ACCESS FULL`; this means it read all the partitions)

**Composite partitioning**

This is "two-level" partitioning. The database first splits the rows on the top-level partition. Then further subdivides on the second level.

A key difference between this and multi-column is you can have different partition methods for each. e.g. range-hash, hash-list, etc.

```
create table t (
  c1 int, c2 int, c3 int
) partition by range ( c1 ) 
  subpartition by range ( c2 )  
  subpartition template (
    subpartition s0 values less than ( 1 ),
    subpartition s100 values less than ( 101 )
  ) (
  partition p0 values less than ( 1 ),
  partition p1 values less than ( 2 ),
  partition p2 values less than ( 3 )
);

insert into t values ( 0, 0,  1 );
insert into t values ( 0, 99, 2 );
insert into t values ( 1, 1,  3 );

select * from t partition ( p0 );

C1     C2     C3   
    0     0     1 
    0    99     2 

select * from t subpartition ( p0_s0 );

C1     C2     C3   
    0     0     1
```

Again, filtering on the subpartition column does minimal partition pruning. The database will first scan all top-level partitions. Then only prune the subpartitions within these:

```
select * from t 
where  c2 = 0;

select * 
from   table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(null, null, 'ROWSTATS LAST +PARTITION'));

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
| Id  | Operation               | Name | Starts | E-Rows | Pstart| Pstop | A-Rows |    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT        |      |      1 |        |       |       |      1 |    
|   1 |  PARTITION RANGE ALL    |      |      1 |      1 |     1 |     3 |      1 |    
|   2 |   PARTITION RANGE SINGLE|      |      3 |      1 |     1 |     1 |      1 |    
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL    | T    |      3 |      1 |       |       |      1 |    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Notice the `PARTITION RANGE SINGLE` operation - this means the database only accessed one of the subpartitions.

Depending on your partitioning scheme and value distribution, this could lead to a decent reduction in rows read. You'll need to try out various partition methods and boundaries to see if this helps you.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work in the case of interval partitions. I found the answer here:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24693_01/server.11203/e16541/part_admin001.htm

Comment: Multi-column doesn't, composite does. That link has examples of interval-range, -list, and -hash tables!

Comment: Dinu, 
You can create interval-range, but not interval/interval. It also depends on the version you're using, which you did not specify (is it 11, as your doc pointer is for that version)?

Answer (score 0):

What I was trying to do is impossible. It is possible to make range partitions using multicolumn partitioning keys, but not if you create interval partitions. More info [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24693_01/server.11203/e16541/part_admin001.htm).